# Receiving Sendgrid Inbound Email webhook attachments as strings (not files)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data, sendgrid

I'm receiving multiple inbound email webhook requests from Sendgrid (a Django/DRF application on my side) with attachments that are strings rather than actual files. This results in an error when trying to save the files (because `'str' object has no attribute 'file'` when trying to `file.read()`). It apparently happens to approx. 5-10% of all inbound emails and seems to only happen with image files (JPGs, GIFs etc), I did not encounter a PDF file passed this way.

Before saving the files I iterate over `attachments-info` keys to get a list of attachments; so here's a list of request data values for keys `attachment1`, `attachment2` in one of these cases (the second one is a file, the first is a string(?):

```
[
'����\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00��\x10�Exif\x00\x00MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x04\x01;\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x08J�i\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x08X��\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1a\x00\x00\x10��\x1c\x00\x07\x00\x00\x08\x0c\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1c�\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00...,
<InMemoryUploadedFile: 40896630.pdf (application/octet-stream)>
]
```

What exactly is this string? Why does that happen? How can I decode it (assuming all I have is the original file name and content type)